# Azure Build Suddenly Fails to Publish Artifact Drop

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops

I'm sure this question will get don voted but I'm rather desperate.  This morning my Visual Studio Team Services build which has ran fro months has suddenly failed with error:

```
Publish build artifacts failed with error: Not found PathtoPublish: C:\a\1\s\$\My Path
```

I do not have direct access to the Azure server but can liaise with support staff.

I can provide more info as required.

Can anyone help troubleshoot please?

Comment: I think this is more related with TFS. Please check your path that used to publish your application.

Comment: Do you queue build with Hosted agent? What's the detail of your build definition? (especially Publish Artifact step)

Comment: Can you share the build logs?

Comment: @davy Do you solve that issue?